# How can send int with ajax to C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api

With, this code I send variable to mvc, but when I am debbuging this code, so web browser give me a error (404)-> Not found and I am sure everything is alright, but with this I am not sure -> data: JSON.stringify(idInfo)

**Ajax-Jquery**

```
function first(idInfo)
{
$.ajax({
            url: "Information/getInformation",
            type: "POST",
            **data: JSON.stringify(idInfo),**
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                ...
            }

        });
```

To this code I need send this varieble.

**C#**

```
[HttpPost]
public information getInformation(int information)
{
...
}
```

Thank you for yor comments and advice.
And I hope I described my problem sufficiently...

Comment: Is the getInformation function actually in a controller called Information?

Comment: What do you see in the network tab? What request is being sent?

Comment: getInformation must return ActionResult,otherwise it's not a controller action and you can't access it like that "Information/getInformation"

Comment: @Selman22 That is not true, you can return pretty much anything and let Web API figure out how to serialize the result (it can even be `void` which means no response body).

Comment: Try `data: "information=" + idInfo,`

Comment: @Selman22, function getInformation have a return, but that isn´t important.

Comment: @SLaks I see in console:
POST http://localhost:10242/Services/Game/GetCurrentTurn?1 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure that the routing is configured correctly. Considering that your API controller looks like the following:

```
public class InformationController : ApiController
{
  [HttpPost]
  public information getInformation(int information)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

In this case, you'd configure the routing the following way:

```
public void Configure(HttpConfiguration config) 
{
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "PostInformationWithId",
    routeTemplate: "Information/getInformation",
    defaults: new { controller = "Information", action = "getInformation" }
  );
}
```

Otherwise (in case you're using default routes), you may need an `api/` prefix for your request URL.

Also, you're sending the `idInfo` via request body (`POST` request) so you either need to mark your `information` parameter as `FromBody` or pass the value via query string:

Using the `FromBody` attribute:

```
public information getInformation([FromBody]int information)
{
  ..
}
```

Passing the parameter via query-string:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "Information/getInformation?information=" + 
    encodeURIComponent(idInfo),
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
    ...
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Problem was in that I don´t have a [FromBody] and encodeURI, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a **slash** beginning of your URL

```
url: "/Information/getInformation",
```

And change `data` like this:

```
data: JSON.stringify( { information : idInfo }),
```

I assume your `Information` is a `Controller`,and `getInformation` is an `Action` which returns an `ActionResult`.

Answer (score 0):

C#

```
public ActionResult UserList([System.Web.Http.FromBody] int distributionType)
```

JS

```
url: "/Share/UserList?distributionType=" + type,
```

works for me.